# Install python package in docker image from my local directory

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

My goal is to copy the python package from my local directory into docker image and execute an installation inside the image, but I got the error as what we can see below. The image link is for my project file tree.

My Docker File Below:

```
FROM python:3.10.1-slim

WORKDIR /copyTrading

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY ccxt.pro-master/python/ /copyTrading

RUN pip install -e .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
    
CMD [ "python", "server2.py"]


------------------------Docker Build Error--------------------------
 => ERROR [5/7] RUN pip install -e .                                                                               9.2s
------
 > [5/7] RUN pip install -e .:
#9 4.734 Obtaining file:///copyTrading
#9 5.433     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#9 5.433      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/copyTrading/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/copyTrading/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-leehc5bu
#9 5.433          cwd: /copyTrading/
#9 5.433     Complete output (7 lines):
#9 5.433     Traceback (most recent call last):
#9 5.433       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#9 5.433       File "/copyTrading/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
#9 5.433         with open(package_json, encoding='utf-8') as f:
#9 5.433       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 905, in open
#9 5.433         file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
#9 5.433     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/package.json'
#9 5.433     ----------------------------------------
#9 5.433 WARNING: Discarding file:///copyTrading. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#9 5.433 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#9 8.817 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.2.1 is available.
#9 8.817 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -e .]: exit code: 1


[Project File Tree][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Zqb.png
```

Comment: Please include the actual error as text and not an image. What does your local project file tree look like?

Comment: Hi @wkl thanks for the response, I edited already my post kindly check.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a package.json file in your container as setup.py was trying to open it trying to install codecs.py. You can try copying that file to its targeted location (/) and see if that resolves it.